# class path resource [org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore/tables_h2.sql] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to use H2 database to test my quartz application which is running using Spring Boot.
My application.properties looks like this :

```
#DB Properties
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:h2:mem:test
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.continueonerror=true

#Quartz
quartz.enabled=true
quartz.initialize-schema=never
org.quartz.jdbc.initialize-schema=never
quartz.schedulerAutoStart=false
quartz.fileName=application-integrationtest.properties
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = DefaultQuartzScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
org.quartz.scheduler.makeSchedulerThreadDaemon = true
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.makeThreadsDaemons = true
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount: 20
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority: 5

#============================================================================
# Configure JobStore
#============================================================================

org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX 
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = false
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = myDs
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 25000


#============================================================================
# Configure Datasources  
#============================================================================

org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.driver = org.h2.Driver
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL = ${spring.datasource.url}
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.maxConnections = 5
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.validationQuery = select 1
```

But it is throwing following exception while running testcase

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'quartzDataSourceInitializer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.CannotReadScriptException: Cannot read SQL script from class path resource [org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore/tables_h2.sql]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore/tables_h2.sql] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1694)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:579)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$120/502891368.getObject(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.CannotReadScriptException: Cannot read SQL script from class path resource [org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore/tables_h2.sql]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore/tables_h2.sql] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:453)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:240)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.AbstractDataSourceInitializer.initialize(AbstractDataSourceInitializer.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:365)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:135)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore/tables_h2.sql] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getReader(EncodedResource.java:146)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.readScript(ScriptUtils.java:282)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:450)
```

Am I missing some configuration?

All quartz related jars dont contain tables_h2.sql. How to include it in my classpath?

Comment: Hello. Please give us more details about what you've done so far, as they are too few material here for us to help you

Comment: @Javadroider has your issue been resolved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just downloaded `quartz` jar from maven repository and there is `table_h2.sql` file there:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz/2.3.0

Also you can find it on github in there quartz github repository: [tables_h2.sql](https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/blob/master/quartz-core/src/main/resources/org/quartz/impl/jdbcjobstore/tables_h2.sql)

So please check if you are not using outdated version of library and you have the right dependency. It looks like these sql files were moved from another package([commit](https://github.com/quartz-scheduler/quartz/commit/990703fbfc1cb5f39eddbe3db078d9c7142a053a)) for `2.3.0` version release, so if you are using latest spring-boot release you either should upgrade quartz or, probably, downgrade spring-boot version.

If you are using spring boot it's recommended to use versions properties specified in `spring-boot-starter-parent`, in your case there is a property `quartz.version` which value is `2.3.0` for `spring-boot 2.0.0.RELEASE`, so in maven it would look like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
    <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
    <version>${quartz.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

In gradle you will have something similar as well.

Comment: Thanks @Ruslan. I was using old quartz. With latest jar my problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution in Spring Boot 2+ (in the case where Quartz is not used) would be to exclude it from the dependency list. In my case i had to add this exclusion. (See your pom file to see the correct groupId and artiactId, because different ones can be used)

I am posting this because the error has lead me to this post.

```
<exclusion>
    <groupId>opensymphony</groupId>
    <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
</exclusion>
```